# Wordpress membership - customization or pre built solutions

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, membership

**Memberships Wordpress Websites**

We are currently working on similar web projects that are restricted to wordpress(by client) and they need extended member functionality.

They have members.

1. Multi/single page registration process with a lot of **profile fields**. basic login/logout.
2. Members should be able to update their profile from fronted page and a dashboard ofc.(user friendly e.g tabs)
3. In wordpress posts have taxonomies, in our case, members are belonging to certain taxonomies(categories) ,predefined by admins(**custom taxonomies**).
4. Member should be able to **CRUD custom post types**. e.g gallery, reviews, events,posts etc.
5. **Admins** should be able to search members based on their meta information.(category,some registration field)

A lot of more such functions/pages even may be member inbox/notifications.

We can do this by extending wordpress default member functionality(roles) , utilizing wordpress custom post types,Wordpress APIs, code out theme or a plugin for one site from scratch.

The problems is we have a lot of projects , whose requirements are one way or the other are same **(NOT EXACTLY SAME)** .

What should be the best option in our case?

Use some pre built membership solution focusing on wordpress and which can be easily extended through templates or WP hooks , if there is any ? *The more we code the more we have to maintain.*

or we should develop our own plugin then extend it on per project bases ?
Code a theme.

Answer (score -1):

After reading your question i think that u should use buddypress with membership plugins.